# How to combine textbox with image when sending mail in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, signature

I want to send mail with text which have size, font, position and else, but also want to include signature which is of course image. So I try to use this code

```
    string htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>This is simple text.</h1><br><img src=\"cid:Pic1\"></body></html>";
    AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

    // Create a LinkedResource object for each embedded image
            LinkedResource pic1 = new LinkedResource("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Pictures\\a.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            pic1.ContentId = "Pic1";
            avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(pic1);

            mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

but it's working only with simple text.

**How to send mail which get text from textbox or pasted text from word and also include signature?**

Comment: Do you set mail.Body somewhere? If I remember correctly the IsBodyHtml property indicates if the Body property should be rendered as HTML. It has no effect on alternate views. Though I doubt this will fix your issue.

Comment: When i put alernativeviews which means that has to be mail.IsBodyHtml on true that waht show my normal body(text and else ...)